# Automatic association and aggregation managment

Tags: c#, associations, aggregate

I have this classes and egzample of use:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars = new List<Bar>();
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo;
}
public void Example()
{
    var f = new Foo();
    var b = new Bar();

    f.Bars.Add(b);
    b.Foo = f;
}
```

is there any way to avoid the last line of code `b.Foo = f;`, so the Bar's Foo property would be automaticly filled with this instance of Foo? I was thinking about some kind of attribute like in this example https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXpoAggregatedAttributetopic because i need this attribute to be generic, not only for Foo and Bar.

My problem is following: is there some kind of build-in .net attribute (or any other structure) that imitates the DevExpress AssociationAttribute behavior and it is usable with a lot of relations? If no - how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one option would be to not expose `List<Bar>` directly and implement the `Add` method:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars => bars.Select(b => b);
    public void AddBar(Bar bar)
    {
        bar.Foo = this;
        bars.Add(bar);
    }
}
```

And now your code would look like:

```
public void Example()
{
    var f = new Foo();
    var b = new Bar();
    f.AddBar(b);
}
```

If you need it to be generic, not only for `Foo` and `Bar` then one way to solve it is to implement an `IChild` interface:

```
public interface IChild<T>
{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And now, you could do the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly List<IChild<Foo>> children = new List<IChild<Foo>>();
    public IEnumerable<IChild<Foo>> Children => children.Select(b => b);
    public void AddChild(IChild<Foo> child)
    {
        children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in real world business classes have a lot of relationships, customer to order, shop, address. Order has to products, manager etc and it's highly repetetive and error prone to use this approach to 5+ relationships

Comment: @BartekWójcik Then use an existing tool for the job, don't reinvent the wheel: for example [Entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723).

Comment: could you please pass me keywords or articles to the topic with ef? Or tools that are seperate from database?